# A single word for a person who encourages terrible rumors about themselves to feel protected

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing a story with a character who was a prince born albino in a very superstitious country. His Uncle intensely feared killing him, as he believed it would release a demon inside of him. This myth becomes the only thing that saves his life when his kingdom is overthrown as a child. He learned that having people falsely fear him keeps him safer than trying to dispel the rumors.

I need a term for someone who encourages his own awful reputation, so that he can win through fear without having to actually be fearsome. Think of [Captain Shakespeare from *Stardust*](http://stardust.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Shakespeare) as being a good example.

The word in a sentence may be used much like the words **illusion** or **facade**. I am not necessarily looking for a noun or an adjective in particular; just a word, or perhaps a short collection of words to explain or describe the concept. Several example sentences include:

> "He was known to ____"
>
> "His ____ was falling to pieces".

Comment: Why do you think such a word exists, and how would you use this word in a sentence?

Comment: I've done a number of hours of research on the idea and concept and still can't seem to come up with a word to convey the concept. I suppose such a word may not exist. Honestly this was my last ditch effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say such a person [***cultivates***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cultivate) [***notoriety***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/notoriety).

[**cultivate**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cultivate)

> Try to acquire or develop (a quality or skill)
>   *‘he cultivated an air of indifference’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cultivate

[**notoriety**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/notoriety)

> The state of being famous or well known for some bad quality or deed.
>   *‘the song has gained some notoriety in the press’*
>   *‘she has a certain notoriety’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/notoriety

Comment: I think 'cultivate' is an excellent suggestion which would allow the writer to explore other phrases, such as 'cultivated the myth of his own inner demon', or cultivated belief that he was a walking time bomb'.

Answer (score 0):

"He was known to *play the bad guy*"

"His *bad guy persona* was falling to pieces".

I *bad guy* is too informal for you, there's always *villain*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of ***propaganda*** (though *usually* propaganda involves spreading *terrible rumors* about *others* or *nice rumors* about oneself).

> "He was known to ***propagandize***".
>
> "His ***propaganda*** was falling to pieces".

M-W:

> **[propaganda](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/propaganda)**
> *noun*
>
> : ideas or statements that are often false or exaggerated and that are
> spread in order to help a cause, a political leader, a government,
> etc.
>
> He was accused of spreading propaganda.
>
> **[propagandize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/propagandize)**
> *verb*
>
> : to spread propaganda
>
> He uses his movies to propagandize for the state.